# Hbase Hadoop integration issue

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to configure Hbase in pseudo distributed mode integrated with Hadoop which is already running in pseudo distributed mode. Hbase-master fails to start.

1.
hbase-site.xml looks like below:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
       <value>true</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
       <value>hdfs://localhost:8030/hbase</value>
   </property>

   <!-- <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>file:/home/hadoop/HBase/HFiles</value>
   </property> -->

   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/home/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

2. hbase-master fails to start and below error is written in hbase-root-master-bdhost.log

   ```
   2016-01-08 17:48:38,333 FATAL [bdhost:16000.activeMasterManager] master.HMaster: Failed to become active master
   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.setSafeMode(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:602)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.fs.HFileSystem$1.invoke(HFileSystem.java:279)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.setSafeMode(DFSClient.java:2264)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:986)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:970)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.isInSafeMode(FSUtils.java:524)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.waitOnSafeMode(FSUtils.java:970)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.checkRootDir(MasterFileSystem.java:417)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.createInitialFileSystemLayout(MasterFileSystem.java:146)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:126)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:649)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.access$500(HMaster.java:182)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$1.run(HMaster.java:1646)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   2016-01-08 17:48:38,334 FATAL [bdhost:16000.activeMasterManager] master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   ....
   ```

I'm using hadoop 2.6.3 and hbase 1.1.2 on Fedora Linux release 21.

Tried disabling selinux, ipv6 but that did not help.

Any pointer is much appreciated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following property try giving the name as rootDir (with an uppercase D) and let me know if it works. Of course make sure the HDFS is running on the port mentioned in the property.

```
    <property>
          <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
          <value>hdfs://localhost:8030/hbase</value>
    </property>
```

- Ravi

Comment: Though most of the documentation shows it it as "rootdir" with a lower case D, upper case is found to be the right way.

Comment: Ohh wow. It worked for me. This wasn't anticipated. Thanks much Ravi.